# How do I detect if the language in the settings for the iPhone has changed from earlier upon start of the application?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I understand that we have to check for it in the App Delegate but I am unable to get what to do for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this function 

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

            print(self.getCurrentLanguageCode())

            return true
        }

    func getCurrentLanguageCode()->String{
            var strLangCode:String = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
            strLangCode = strLangCode.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "_")
            if let regionCode:String = Locale.current.regionCode {
                if strLangCode.contains("_" + regionCode) {
                    strLangCode = strLangCode.replacingOccurrences(of: "_" + regionCode, with: "")
                }
            }
            return strLangCode
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current setting language as below

```
Locale.current.languageCode
```

> Output: en